# Existence of solution outside the interval predicted by Picard's theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Q. If the solution to $$\begin{cases}
   \frac{dy}{dx}=y^2+x^2,& x>0\\y(0)=2 \end{cases},~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(*)$$ exists in the interval $[0,L_0)$ and the maximal interval of existence of $$\begin{cases}
   \frac{dz}{dx}=z^2, & x>0\\z(0)=1, \end{cases}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(**)$$ is $[0,L_1),$ then which of the following statements are correct?

1. $L_1=1, ~~~~~~~L_0>1$
2. $L_1=1, ~~~~~~~L_0\leq1$
3. $L_1<2, ~~~~~~~L_0\leq1$
4. $L_1>2, ~~~~~~~L_0<1$

It is very easy to see $L_1=1$ for the very commen problem $(**)$, and, I got the solution to $(*)$ exists in the interval $[0,L_0)$ for $L_0 \leq 1$ by the prediction of Picard's theorem (on the interval $|x| \leq h=\min\{a, b/M\}$,~$M$ can be taken as $|f(x,y)| \leq |x^2|+|y^2|<a^2+(2+b)^2=M$). But, Can I confirm that $L_0 \not >1$ here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution $y$ of $(*)$ on $[0, L_0)$ is strictly positive and satisfies $y'(x) \ge y(x)^2$, therefore is
$$
 x = \int_0^x 1 \, dt \le \int_0^x \frac{y'(t)}{y(t)^2} \, dt
= \frac{1}{y(0)} - \frac{1}{y(x)} < \frac{1}{y(0)}  = \frac 12
$$
for all $x \in [0, L_0)$. This gives the estimate $L_0 \le 1/2$ for the interval of existence.